# How can I correctly call this function?

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble calling this function. It's supposed to reformat a name from "First Mid Last" to "Last, First MidInitial" (If a middle name is available, else just "Last, First)). Though if I change the function type to string, it gives a different list of errors:

```
In function âvoid getData(StudentType*, int)â:
71:43: error: invalid use of void expression
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

---

PROGRAM FILE

---

```
using namespace std;
#include "StudentType.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <climits>
#include <string>

const int MAX_STDS = 20;

void getData(StudentType[], int&);

void sortData(StudentType[], int&);

void getFormat(string& name);

void computeAverages(StudentType[], int&);

void printData(StudentType[], int&);


int main () {

StudentType students[MAX_STDS];
StudentType();
int n;

getData(students, n);
sortData(students, n);
computeAverages(students, n);
printData(students, n);

return 0;
}

void getData(StudentType students[], int n){
    ifstream fin;
    int grade;
    string filename, name;
    bool done = false;

    cout << "Enter filename: ";
    cin >> filename;
    fin.open(filename.c_str());
    while(true) {
       try {
         fin.open(filename.c_str());
         if(!fin) {
            throw(string("Could not open " + filename + "."));
         }
         break;
       }
       catch (string s) {
          cout << s << endl;
          cout << "Enter a different file name: ";
          cin >> filename;
       }
    }
    n=0;
    while(n<MAX_STDS && getline(fin, name)) {
       students[n].setName(getFormat(name));
       for(int i = 0; i < NUM_GRDS; ++i) {
          fin >> grade;
          students[n].setGrade(grade, i);
       }
       getline(fin, name);
       ++n;
    }
}

void printData(StudentType students[], int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
       students[i].printLine();
    }
}

void computeAverages(StudentType students[], int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
       students[i].computeAverage();
    }
}

void sortData(StudentType students[], int n) {
    for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
       for(int j=0; j < n-1-i; ++j) {
          if(students[j].getName() > students[j+1].getName()) {
             swap(students[j], students[j+1]);
          }
       }
    }
}

void getFormat(string name) {
    string first;
    string middle;
    string last;
    char n, m;
    int size = 0;
    n = name.find(' ');
    first = name.substr(0, n);
    m = name.find(' ', n + 1);
    size = name.size();
    if (m != string::npos) {
       middle = name.substr(n+1, m-(n+1));
       last = name.substr(m+1, size - (m+1));
    }
    else {
       middle = "";
       last = name.substr(n + 1, size - (n + 1));
    }
    name = last + ", " + first;
    if (middle != "") {
       name = (name + ' ') + middle[0];
    }
}
```

---

HEADER FILE

---

```
#ifndef STUDENTTYPE__H
#define STUDENTTYPE__H

#include <string>
#include<iostream>

const int NUM_GRDS = 10;

class StudentType {
   public:
      StudentType();
      void setName(std::string);
      void setGrade(int, int);
      void computeAverage();
      std::string getName() const;
      void printLine(std::ostream& = std::cout) const;
   private:
      std::string name;
      int grades[NUM_GRDS];
      float avg;
};

#endif
```

---

IMPLEMENTATION FILE

---

```
#include "StudentType.h"
#include <iomanip>

StudentType::StudentType(){
    name = "";
    for(int i =0; i <NUM_GRDS; ++i){
       grades[i] = 0;
    }
    avg = 0.0;
}

void StudentType::setName(std::string newName){
    name = newName;
}

void StudentType::setGrade(int grade, int num){
    grades[num] = grade;
}

void StudentType::computeAverage(){
    float total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<NUM_GRDS; ++i){
       total += grades[i];
    }
    avg = total/NUM_GRDS;
}

std::string StudentType::getName() const{
    return name;
}

void StudentType::printLine(std::ostream& out) const {
//    out.setf(ios::left);
//    out.setf(ios::fixed);
//    out.setf(ios::showpoint);
    out << "\n" << std::setw(25) << "Student" << std::setw(50)
        << "Grades" << std::setw(10) << "Average" << std::endl;
    out << "_____________________________________________________________________________________" << std::endl;
    out << std::left << std::setw(25) << name << std::right << ' ';
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_GRDS; ++i){
    out << std::setw(5) << grades[i] << ' ';
    }
    out << std::setprecision(2) << std::setw(6) << avg << std::endl;
}

int main (){

return 0;
}
```

---

My output should look like this after the program compiles...

---

```
Enter file name: grades.dat

Student                  Grades                                            Average
________________________________________________________________________________________
Last, First              90   80   70   60   50   40   30   20   10   0    45.00
Last, First              40   40   40   40   40   40   40   40   40   40   40.00
Last, First              54   98   65   32   21   87   54   65   98   32   60.60
Flames, Blood A          9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    0    4.50
Bottoms, Car             32   65   98   87   54   24   56   89   78   68   65.10
Guitars, Dean            10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10.00
Honer, Ruth T            78   56   12   23   45   89   31   64   97   79   57.40
Hot, Zepher R            12   54   87   89   56   32   51   46   97   31   55.50
.
.
.
```

The input file should have this format and include over 20 students for testing purposes:
g0, g1,...g9 should be 10 grades ranging from 0 to 100

```
First Middle Last
g0 g1 g2 g3 g4 g5 g6 g7 g8 g9
First Last
g0 g1 g2 g3 g4 g5 g6 g7 g8 g9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error specifies that you are misusing a function with a void return type.

In your example, you can see this line:

```
students[n].setName(getFormat(name));
```

According to the definition, the *getFormat()* function is returning void and the setName method is expecting *std::string*.

Also, I spotted a multiple definition for *main()* which will fail to link. Look at the end of your student type implementation file.

Comment: How then, do I compile my implementation file? When I delete the empty main I get this error:  {/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.6/../../../crt1.o: In function `_start':
/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/glibc-2.14.1/csu/../sysdeps/i386/elf/start.S:115: undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
}

Comment: The correct signature for main is

int main(int argc, char** argv)

you can ignore the parameters if you do not need the command line arguments. However, they will be required to link.

Comment: I'm new to this object programming, so bare with me here: In my main program file, My main function should look similar to this format  int main(int argc, char** argv)? Also, if so, I'm unclear of what my arguments should be...

Comment: I will clarify things a bit, although the complete signature for main is the one I provided in my last comment, any of "void main()", "int main()" or "int main(int argc, char** argv)" should do. Therefore, I would ask if all your code gets compiled ? Can you provide details on how you compile the code ? I am looking for the commands you type.

Comment: I'm using a command line shell. The command i'm typing is 'g++ Program04.cpp StudentType.cpp'

Comment: okay, so I added my & onto each function definition and it compiles. On the other hand, it refuses every input file I try.. This I really don't get because its the same function I have used in previous programs that did the same thing this one does.

Comment: Glad, you could compile your program. I suggest you run it in a debugger like gdb (maybe use a front end like DDD) and you shall found the problem. Cheers. :)